# Auto Hiding button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have a hover bar at the top left that when you hover over it, it transitions outward and displays a button which you can press to display more options, but when you suddenly mouse over and go away again, it doesn't look smooth as the button doesn't fade with the div and the button kind of turns square when it the div fades back in. How could I fix it?

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * screen.width;
    var y = Math.random() * screen.height;
    var star = document.createElement('div');
    star.className = 'star';
    star.style.left = x + 'px';
    star.style.top = y + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(star);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('.mercury-lines').toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fade").hover(function() {
    $("button").fadeToggle(1500);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#fade {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #848484;
  transition: width 2s;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10%;
  top: 10px;
  left: -8px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
#fade:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
.star {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*box-shadow: rgb(204, 153, 0) 0px 0px 50px 0px;*/
}
#button-change {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
}
.mercury {
  position: absolute;
  height: 18px;
  /*25px for both*/
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*box-shadow: green 0 0 25px;*/
}
.mercury-orbit {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -101px;
  margin-top: -101px;
  -webkit-animation: spin-left 30s linear infinite;
}
.mercury-lines {
  display: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -113px;
  margin-top: -113px;
}
.moon {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.moon-orbit {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-bottom: -34px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-left 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-left {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Solar System</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <img class="sun" src="http://www.mprgroup.net/images/august2011/sun_transparent.png">
  <div class="mercury-lines">
  </div>

  <div class="mercury-orbit ">
    <img class="mercury" src="http://astronomyandlaw.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/mercury.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="fade">
    <button id="button-change">Toggle Orbits</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would not animate the width of the hover bar but the alignment of it. So the width stays the same the whole time but when you hover over it, it gradually moves to the right which has the same effect. That way the button which is contained inside does not have to wrap. Another plus is that the button moves too, which looks nicer imo.

Comment: Could you show me the answer in code please?

Comment: Sorry my CSS is very shaky. In the past I usually did this kind of things with jQuery. Give the hover bar a fixed  witdth and animate the `left` property to move it left and right. If jQuery is acceptable for you: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: If you're experienced in Jquery, could you give me an example in that then please?

Comment: here you go: http://jsbin.com/wahoputuhu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Do you know why it sometimes glitches when you hover over it straight away after you visit the webpage? It like goes in, out then in and out again?

Answer (score 1):

add this for each of your #fade and #button-change in your css

```
 #fade{
     overflow:hidden;
    }
```

and spacify the width to button

```
#button-change{
 width: 100px;
}
```

but let me say that's not a good solution .. you can margin left your #fade and animate it .. I think it will be better

[**DEMO HERE Using js**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kwgnxu2/2/) 
in css

```
    #fade{
      margin-left :-180px;
    }
```

in js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#fade').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'margin-left':'0px'},2000);
      });
      $('#fade').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'margin-left':'-180px'},2000);
      });
    });
```

and use all of your code inside just one $(document).ready  no need to repeat that

[**DEMO HERE Using css**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kwgnxu2/3/) you can do that with pure css

```
#fade{
   margin-left :-180px;
   transition-duration: 2s;
}
#fade:hover{
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why it sometimes glitches when you hover over it straight away after you visit the webpage? It like goes in, out then in and out again?

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not the best answer but solves the problem,hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fade").mouseover(function() {
    $("button").fadeIn(1500);
  });

  $("#fade").mouseout(function() {
    $("button").hide();
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87L07c92/)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Why this is not the best answer?